# Supercaps and discharge

Tags: boost, supercapacitor

I know that capacitors discharge quickly, but it seems like there has to be a way to replace deep cycle batteries. A capacitor with a constant current source that is rated to drain the cap slowly, should allow the cap to act like a battery, yes? Isn't a boost converter a constant current source (or variable but not so high as to drain the cap bank)?

To be clear, I am wanting to use caps for a datacenter 8 hour backup, but I imagine solar and other enthusiasts want to know.

Comment: Fast discharge is synonymous with low energy density = bad for 8 hours with or without a boost converter. You're missing the forest for the trees by focusing on boosting the voltage.

Comment: Thanks for not reading before answer. I am suggesting a current drain much lower than the energy capacity of the caps.

Comment: Irrelevant because the low energy density problem is MUCH more severe than you are thinking.

Comment: Still, caps are capable of high currents - and this is basically already suggesting, that the energy density is not very good compared to batteries.

Comment: 1) the energy stored in a capacitor is E = CV^2 (see: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capeng.html). 2) Determine how much energy is needed for "datacenter 8 hour backup" 3) Play with the calculator from the hyperphysics link and find a solution to get the amount of energy you need. 4) compare to a battery based solution. 5) conclude that super capacitor technology simply isn't there yet, you'd need far more volume (for all the caps) and money compared to a traditional battery based solution.

Comment: How big is the power consumption of your datacenter? Just calculate the capacity you would need to supply the necessary energy and you will see that this is lost hope.

Comment: OK. What about a typical home? And the real question, remember, is can the caps replace batteries if the current source is limited.

Comment: @BitcoinNeeder In short, no. Because what you need to worry about is energy, not current. Capacitors don't hold a lot of energy, and there is no getting around that fact.

Comment: *What about a typical home?* Don't change the question! My procedure is universal as it simply compares energy stored (in a cap) to energy needed. So for a "typical home" or a supercapacitor powered gadget, the equations are the same. If you want to know: do the calculation. Also see where supercaps are actually used in products because that's where there is an advantage (if not the manufacturer would have used a battery). I'll give one example: a real-time clock inside a measurement product. Even for that solution: I simple coin cell is hard to beat.

Comment: Bimpelrekkie, I wish to thank you for assuming I am not an idiot and providing real facts. Yes, we did this exercise. At the rate we can have the new large supercaps made in Japan, we can store the energy needed. I just need to know how to slow down the rate of discharge. Voltage loss is obvious as discharge happens, but the inverters work on variable input voltage. We calculated for that too.

Comment: Then prove that by showing the numbers because typically the supercap solution isn't viable. So show the numbers, capacity, maximum charge voltage etc. The voltage might have an impact on implementation. Most supercaps are 2.7 V which is a pain. As stored energy is proportional to V^2 a higher voltage helps a lot (yeah, caps in series increases voltage but decreases capacitance!). If we know the numbers we can think about a DCDC (or DCAC) converter to convert the stored charge into a useful voltage.

Comment: Are you talking about the rate of self-discharge?  Because the only other way to lower the rate of discharge is to lower the load consumption.  Energy in = energy out minus some losses, you obviously cannot get around that.

Comment: _"... but it seems like there has to be a way to replace deep cycle batteries."_ - Why does it seem like there _has to be_?

Comment: Yes, switching converters can work over a range of voltages, but you can't get more power out than you put in. As the input voltage goes down, the input current **must go up** to maintain the same power out. That's why talking in terms of **energy** is the right way to analyze this problem.

Answer (score 7):

**Yes, you can use switching power supply topologies to slowly and safely discharge a large capacitor bank. These can be controlled to create exactly the load current you need.** Basically every switching power supply has some DC intermediate circuit with a capacitor bank, exactly as you described above.

Still, the remark from the comments seems to be limiting factor here. First you talked about datacenter usage, then you changed to a typical home.
Let's just assume an average consumption of 2kW during the 8h. This seems legit for home usage, but is way to low for a datacenter.

\$ 2 kW * 8h = 16 kWh = 57.6 MJ.\$
This is the energy we somehow need to store in the capacitors.

\$ 57.6 MJ = E_{Cap} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot CU^2\$

I just checked at a big electronics distributor and the "best" solution I could find would be an 8.4 V supercap with 15 F.

\$ C = \frac{ 2\cdot E}{U^2} = \frac{2 \cdot 57.6 MJ}{(8.4 V)^2} = 1.6 MF \$
Megafarad. Mega. Farad.
With the above mentioned capacitor with 15 F each this would just require... 100,000 peaces! With a price of ~15$/piece you can calculate the cost of this. And this calculation assumes that the switching power supply can discharge the caps with 100% effiency over the complete voltage range down to 0 V. Not likely.

And now let's not talk about a supply for a datacenter, right?

Comment: I think your first statement is misleading. If the switching converter has some specified input voltage and you need some specified amount of power out, you **can not** arbitrarily control the current drawn from the capacitor. The "exactly what you need" is really "exactly what **the load** needs", plus a bit more because the power supply is not 100% efficient.

Comment: Well yeah, that is true, when the caps are discharging and voltage decreases, the discharge current has to increase (for U->0 the current would theoratically go to infinity. But because voltage squared law, the energy left in the cap is negelctable for low voltages). But the current on the output of the supply is stable and of the desired value the whole time.

Comment: Looking at this again, I think the issue is where you placed the word **with** in your first sentence. It looks to me as though you meant "discharge....with exactly the current" but maybe you meant "use switching...with exactly the current [**to the load**]"  In any event, it is best to avoid complex sentence structure when explaining engineering concepts.

Comment: I changed the first sentance, now it should be clearer.